# TransactionScope não efetua transações

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando utilizar o `TransactionScope` no C#, estou realizando os testes com banco local, mas toda vez que tento executar algum método ele me retorna essa exception:

**O gerenciador de transações de parceiros desativou seu suporte a transações remotas/de rede. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8004D025)**

Já ativei o **Coordenador de transações distribuídas** nos serviços e **DTC Local** nos Serviços de Componente, sem sucesso.

Parte parcial do código:

```
try
{
    using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
    {
        while (contadorInicial <= contadorFinal)
        {
            Objeto.Codigo = contadorInicial.ToString();
            _objController.Insert(Objeto);
            contadorInicial++;
        }

        trans.Complete();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

São vários passos para habilitar o suporte a transações distribuídas:

1. Ferramentas Administrativas > Serviços
2. Habilite o *Coordenador de Transações Distribuídas* se ele estiver desativado;
3. Volte em Ferramentas Administrativas > Serviços de Componente;
4. Vá em Serviços de Componente > Computadores > Meu Computador > Botão direito > Propriedades;
5. Na aba `MSDTC`, clique em `Configurações de Segurança`;
6. Verifique se estão checados "Acesso à Rede DTC", "Permitir Cliente Remoto", "Permitir Conexões de Entrada/Saída", "Habilitar TIP";
7. Aplique as configurações e reinicie o computador.

Se não for necessário usar o `TransactionScope` necessariamente, experimente as seguintes alternativas:

### 1. Usando Entity Framework

```
using (var tx = context.BeginTransaction())
{
    while (contadorInicial <= contadorFinal)
    {
        Objeto.Codigo = contadorInicial.ToString();
        _objController.Insert(Objeto);
        contadorInicial++;
    }

    tx.Commit();
}
```

### 2. Usando SqlConnection ou algum derivado

```
// connection é uma SqlConnection inicializada.
using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    while (contadorInicial <= contadorFinal)
    {
        Objeto.Codigo = contadorInicial.ToString();
        _objController.Insert(Objeto);
        contadorInicial++;
    }

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Vale aqui uma observação: não sei como funciona sua DAO. Em todo caso, seria legal seu método de inserção aceitar uma transação ou um contexto como parâmetro opcional.

Comment: Realizei todos os procedimentos mas continua ocorrendo o mesmo erro, o que posso fazer? (Estou tentando realizar esses procedimentos no computador do trabalho, e os computadores estão numa rede que é controlada pelo setor de TI), será que é por causa disso?

Comment: É. O servidor de banco de dados está em outra máquina?

Comment: Não, é uma instância local do SQL Server.

Comment: Existe uma alternativa ao TransactionScope que eu poderia usar?

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou com SqlConnection!