# BeginTransaction vs TransactionScope

Tags: entity-framework, transações

Eu estava analisando [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16330/23192) e surgiu a dúvida:

Qual a diferença entre `BeginTransaction` e o `TransactionScope`? Existem situações específicas para cada um? Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens em comparação um com o outro?

Comment: @Jedais, não estou podendo responder agora, mas a diferença entre ambos, assim como os pros e contras são explicados na [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843)

Answer (score 1):

Jedais, se estiver utilizando `Entity Framework` versão 5 ou anterior, você terá de utilizar o `TransactionScope` caso queira utilizar uma transação unica para mais de uma operação.

A partir do `EF6`, o mesmo passou a incoporou os métodos `BeginTransaction` e `UseTransaction` à propriedade `Database`, desta forma é possivel reaproveitar a mesma transação em mais de uma operação.

Uma outra alteração no `EF6`, é que o mesmo passou a aceitar uma conexão já aberta, desta forma podemos chamar o `sqlConnection.BeginTransaction` e então passar esta conexão como argumento na inicialização do `DbContext`.

Um outro ponto é quanto a operações Assicronas, caso o seu targetFramework será uma versão anterior ao `4.5.1`, então o `TransactionScope` não irá funcionar, então a sua unica opção é o `BeginTransaction`

Para a maioria dos cenarios, o `BeginTransaction` é mais do que suficiente, e não há a necessidade de um `TransactionScope`, porém é mais facil de se trabalhar com o `TransactionScope` em dois cenarios.

**Transações Distribuidas**

Caso a sua transação evolva mais de uma conexão, o `TransactionScope` irá converter a sua transação local em uma transação distribuida de forma automatica.

**Recources Volateis**

`BeginTransaction` mantem à sua transação apenas a nivel do `Bando de Dados`, se precisar que algum objeto em memoria também sofra um `Rollback`/`Commit`, este objeto poderá implementar a interface `IEnlistmentNotification` e ser adicionado a transação.

segue um exemplo retirado da [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {

            //Create an enlistment object
            myEnlistmentClass myElistment = new myEnlistmentClass();

            //Enlist on the current transaction with the enlistment object
            Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(myElistment, EnlistmentOptions.None);

            //Perform transactional work here.

            //Call complete on the TransactionScope based on console input
            ConsoleKeyInfo c;
            while(true)
            {
                Console.Write("Complete the transaction scope? [Y|N] ");
                c = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();

                if ((c.KeyChar == 'Y') || (c.KeyChar == 'y'))
                {
                    scope.Complete();
                    break;
                }
                else if ((c.KeyChar == 'N') || (c.KeyChar == 'n'))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Transactions.TransactionException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot complete transaction");
        throw;
    }
}

class myEnlistmentClass : IEnlistmentNotification
{
    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prepare notification received");

        //Perform transactional work

        //If work finished correctly, reply prepared
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();

        // otherwise, do a ForceRollback
        preparingEnlistment.ForceRollback();
    }

    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Commit notification received");

        //Do any work necessary when commit notification is received

        //Declare done on the enlistment
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rollback notification received");

        //Do any work necessary when rollback notification is received

        //Declare done on the enlistment
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In doubt notification received");

        //Do any work necessary when indout notification is received

        //Declare done on the enlistment
        enlistment.Done();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ótima sua colocação entre as duas versões do EF!